# Promise chaining causing increased execution time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, imagemagick

I am create a simple `NODE-JS` function that Converts `PDF` to `Image` > Crops `Image` > Merge Them back with `ImageMagick`.

and this is the complete code i am using :

```
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var gs = require('node-gs');
var sharp = require('sharp');
var areaMap = require('./areaMap');
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;
var pExcep = 'someException';

var gsPath = 'Ghostscript/gs26';
var src = path.join(os.tmpdir(), '/');

var Files = {
  file1: path.join(src, 'out1.jpeg'),
  file2: path.join(src, 'out2.jpeg'),
  OutImg: path.join(src, 'out.jpeg')
}

var crop = function (s, sFile) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    s = areaMap[s];
    sharp(Files.OutImg).extract(s)
      .toFile(sFile)
      .then(()=> res())
      .catch((err) => rej(err));
  });
};

var getBaseCard = function (s) {
  if (RegExp('^([0-9]{8})$').test(s)) { return 'SOMETHINGHERE' } else { return 'inception'; }
  //This can be done on client side.
}

var GetCardType = function (base, sInfo) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    if (base === 'SOEMTHINGHERE') {
      if (sInfo.includes('SOMETHINGHERE2')) {
        if (sInfo.includes(pExcep)) {
          res('PA_S_')
        } else {
          res('PA_S2')
        }
      } else {
        res('PA_ST')
      }
    } else {
      res('SA_')
    }
  })
}

var PdfToText = function (file, pass) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    gs()
      .batch().safer().nopause().res(2).option('-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=20').option('-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=20').option('-dFIXEDMEDIA').option('-sPDFPassword=' + pass).device('txtwrite').output('-').input(file).executablePath(gsPath)
      .exec((err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (!err) {
          res(stdout);
        } else {
          console.log(stdout);
          console.log(err);
          console.log(stderr);
        }
      })
  });
}

var getBaseImage = function (file, pass, quality) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    gs()
      .batch().nopause().safer().res(300 * quality).option('-dTextAlphaBits=4').option('-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4').option('-sPDFPassword=' + pass)
      .executablePath(gsPath).device('jpeg').output(Files.OutImg).input(file)
      .exec((err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (!err) { res(); } else { rej(stdout) };
      })
  })
}

exports.processCard = function (file, password, quality) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getBaseImage(file, password, quality) // Convert PDF to Image
      .then(() => {
        PdfToText(file, password) // Extract Text from pdf
          .then((res) => {
            GetCardType(getBaseCard(password), res) // finally get PDF Type
              .then((ct) => {
                // crop image here using Sharp
                Promise.all([ 
                  crop(ct + 'A_' + quality, Files.file1),  
                  crop(ct + 'B_' + quality, Files.file2)])
                  .then(() => {
                    // Merge Above two image into one using ImageMagick convert
                    spawn('convert', [Files.file1, Files.file2, '+append', 'files/out1.jpg']);
                    fs.unlinkSync(Files.OutImg); // Unlink tmp folders
                    fs.unlinkSync(Files.file1);
                    fs.unlinkSync(Files.file2);
                    resolve(); // finally resolve
                  }).catch((err) => reject(err));
              }).catch((err) => reject(err))
          }).catch((err) => reject(err))
      }).catch((err) => reject(err))
  })
}
```

and now these are the problem i am facing:

```
 1. ImageMagick isn't creating the output file.
 2. fs.unlinksysnc throws ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/tmp/out1.jpeg' 
    on average every second execution.

 3. Using above code increases execution time.
    For Example: getBaseImage should complete in 600ms but it takes 1400 using above code.
```

About speed in General it (The Complete `Function` not just `getBaseImage`) should finish in 1100-1500ms(*) on average but the time taken is ~2500ms.

*1100-1500ms time is achievable by using function chaining but that is hard to read and maintaine for me.

I am going to use this function in `Firebase Functions`.

How to properly chain these functions ?

***EDIT***

```
exports.processCard = function (file, password, quality) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(performance.now());
    getBaseImage(file, password, quality) //Convert PDF TO IMAGE
      .then(() => { return PdfToText(file, password) })
      .then((res) => {return GetCardType(getBaseCard(password), res) })
      .then((ct) => {
        return Promise.all([
          crop(ct + 'A_' + quality, Files.file1),
          crop(ct + 'B_' + quality, Files.file2)])
      })
      .then(() => {
        spawn('convert', [Files.file1, Files.file2, '+append', 'files/out1.jpg']);
        fs.unlinkSync(Files.OutImg); // Unlink tmp folders
        fs.unlinkSync(Files.file1);
        fs.unlinkSync(Files.file2);
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
```

Using above pattern didn't solved my issues here.

Comment: Best to avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern, and the nested `.then`-as-callback antipattern, to start with, would make the code much cleaner

Comment: version of nodejs will be important to this question.  OP, post complete environment.  of possible interest: https://blog.kuzzle.io/bluebird-vs-native-vs-async/await-state-of-promises-performances-in-2019

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hii please see the OP for Edit for the nested chaining ?

Comment: @user120242 Hii The installed version of node on my system is 12.16.1 but as i will be using this code in Firebase function so it have to be compatible with node8

Comment: Although it doesn't look like it should be the cause for 1s difference in performance, try using Bluebird promises.  It's a quick replacement.

Comment: Is the call `.then(res())` in `crop` intentional?  It looks like crop will always resolve with undefined immediately?  Also, if this code doesn't work the performance characteristics aren't meaningful either?

Comment: @user120242 Whoopsieee!! Typo there..

Comment: You should make the 3 calls to `unlink` in parallel by wrapping the call with a promise and use Promise.all

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance this weirdness is caused by using the file system. If I understand it correctly, the fs in cloud functions is in memory, so when you write to it, read from it, and remove from it, you're using more and less os memory. That can get weird if a function is called repeatedly and re uses the loaded module.

One thing to try to keep the state clean for each invocation is to put everything  (including the requires) inside the scope of the handler. That way you instantiate everything freshly on each invocation.

Finally, you don't seem to be waiting for the spawned convert command to run, you'll need to wait for it to complete:

```
const convertProc = spawn('convert', [Files.file1, Files.file2, '+append', 'files/out1.jpg']);
convertProc.on('close', function() {
 fs.unlinkSync(Files.OutImg); // Unlink tmp folders
 fs.unlinkSync(Files.file1);
 fs.unlinkSync(Files.file2);
 resolve();
})
convertProc.on('close', function(error) {
  reject(error);
});
```

Then you wait for it to complete before you resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your time. if i don't store temps in fs or use them from variable i don't find any difference. Actually the only difference is coming in `getBaseImage` call. that should be about 400-500ms but is going upto 1600ms. and i used `spawnSync` for convert call. so the code is working but the problem is increased time of execution for no reason.(or some)

Comment: How are you comparing the execution times? Local vs cloud function? Is it slow every time or do multiple repeated calls speed up? Just wondering if, since the slow operation is the first operation, maybe it's a cold start issue that you don't see outside of cloud functions?

Also, kinda unrelated, but node 8 supports async functions so you really don't need to do all this nested promise chaining stuff.

Comment: By which I mean, that whole processCard fn can be:
Edit: cant do code blocks in comments, try here: https://pastebin.com/Advz3J67

Comment: I used this but using async makes output file of GS `jpeg` corrupt , while cropping sharp throws error corrupt image data at line 720 and random. don't know why.  I am comparing result on local machine. i know about cold starts but i haven't yet deployed it.

Comment: async and await are just wrappers around Promises, so if it works with one it should work with the other. It’s more likely you weren’t awaiting something which was meaning one step started before the previous one finished. If you’re comparing local with local it might be helpful if you post the code that’s running faster. Then maybe we can see what’s causing the difference.